# link my eclipse project to SVN

Tags: svn

i have a project in eclipse which was on SVN but some how its not connected to SVN now ,I am trying to update it on svn again by just going to my project ->Team ->Share Project

There i can already see the SVN metadata folders for this project, If I Want to proceed i have to ckeck the option of "continue and have subclipse just remove those folders for you"

I am confused , should i continue with removing those folders , or there's some better way of connecting my project to SVN.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about metadata folders (plural), maybe your SVN client was upgraded to 1.7?  Clients at version 1.7 require that you upgrade your working copy, and it results in a single metadata folder at the top level.

See:  http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html
Also potentially helpful:  http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html

You can always make a backup copy of your checked-out directory and experiment.